Random shuffle rows and columns but retain names for columns and rows in C++
I am trying to shuffle rows and columns in C++ 11, where the aim is to retain the rows and column names. I am able to generate the shuffled matrix, but the names are not retained.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>  // For std::istringstream
#include "util/base.hpp"




void writeMatrix(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrix, const std::string& out_file_name) {
    std::ofstream file(out_file_name);
    for (const auto& row : matrix) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
            file << row[i];
            if (i != row.size() - 1) file << "\t"; // Use tab as delimiter
        }
        file << "\n";
    }
    file.close();
}


// Function to permute a matrix
void permuteMatrix(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrix, std::mt19937& g) {
    for (auto& row : matrix) {
        std::shuffle(row.begin(), row.end(), g);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 5) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <input file> <output file base> <number of permutations> <seed>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string inputFile = argv[1];
    std::string outputFileBase = argv[2];
    int numPermutations = std::stoi(argv[3]);
    int seed = std::stoi(argv[4]);
    

    // read file
    std::vector<std::string> annotation_vec;
    std::vector<std::string> gene_name_vec;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix;
    load(inputFile, annotation_vec, gene_name_vec, matrix);


    // Create a random number generator
    std::mt19937 g(seed);

    // Perform permutations and write to files
    for (int i = 0; i < numPermutations; ++i) {
        auto permutedMatrix = matrix;  // Copy original matrix to preserve it
        permuteMatrix(permutedMatrix, g); // Shuffle each row

        // Create a filename for each permutation
        std::string out_file_name = outputFileBase + "_permutation" + std::to_string(i + 1) + ".txt";
        writeMatrix(permutedMatrix, out_file_name);
    }

    return 0;
}

The base.hpp can be found on github, essentially the aim is to undertake random permutations of the original matrix, and then to undertake pearson/spearman correlation and investigate if the fdr of the random permutated correlation pairs are higher than from a biological sample, as a measure to address the null hypothesis.

It looks like permuteMatrix() shuffles each row independently, such that the values originally contained in each column would no longer be arranged in a column afterwards.  Is that intentional?  If so, it's not clear how the column names should be ordered afterwards.

Build two vectors of indices representing the ordering of rows and columns. Shuffle each of those vectors, then use them as a mapping to reorder your rows and columns.

where are the row names and column names?
